# JSON shown on screen instead of pushed to variables

Tags: php, json

I have been trying to script an code to retrieve entry's from a webshop using an API. Using this code

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://api.mijnwebwinkel.nl/v1/orders?language=nl_NL&limit=10&start_date=2017-04-10&end_date=2017-04-20&format=json&ordering=asc&partner_token=xxx&token=xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

// execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I am getting the result directly printed on my screen and I really don't know why this happens, since there is no code to do this.

[image]

Normally I use `$data = json_decode($result);` to convert json and be able to use it as an variable like echo `$data->url;` but that is not working.

So how can I prevent the output from being shown and why can;t I convert is to a variable.

EDIT

I have added RETURNTRANSFER as mentioned in an comment.
When i use `print_r($data);` I see an array

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [number] => 3172023 [date] =>
>   2017-04-14 [time] => 13:46:51 [status] => 4 [status_changed_date] =>
>   2017-04-17 [status_changed_time] => 21:11:47 [weight] => 150
>   [finished] => [taxed] => include [locale] => nl_NL [comments] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [customer] => Conform afspraak levering op
>   bovengenoemd adres van 295 -100-60 cm , 2 mm dik, met rand binnenzijde
>   van 15 cm, cortenstaal plantenbak, zonder bodem. ) [payment] => stdCla

I have been trying to get an output with

```
foreach ($data['stdClass Object'] as $object)
{
    echo "items:". $object['number'] ."\n";
};
```

Resulting in

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: CURL outputs result by default. To prevent outputting use `RETURNTRANSFER` option. Reading a manual can help sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, cURL outputs response by default. To prevent this you should set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to `true`.

Going further - `stdClass Object` in your output is **not** a key. It's name of a class. So, first element of your array is `object` of class `stdClass`.

Iterating over array is:

```
foreach ($data as $object)
{
    // `$object` is a stdClass object
    // accessing object properties is done with `->`
    echo "items:". $object->number ."\n";
};
```

Or you can `json_decode` your response with second parameter set to `true`. And all items will be arrays:

```
json_decode($result, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the output of print_r and var_dump, 'stdClass Object' represents the data type, not the name of the variable.

Try using this code instead

```
foreach ($data as $object)
{
    echo "items:". $object['number'] ."\n";
};
```